# Backbone (Marionette) Edit View

Tags: backbone.js, view, marionette

How can I implement an editable view? For example, I have a `PersonView`. The default view will be showing the person info. Then when I double click, I want to enter "edit mode" where I can edit fields. I suppose you can imagine what I mean? Its common "pattern". How can I implement it? The "simple" way might be on `dblClick` I replace existing HTML with something else. But it doesnt seem right ... How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this in many ways:
swapping views,
inline editing,
swapping templates

here is a nice tutorial explaining what you need:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-4/

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your text fields some class, for example `.disabled`. Also you have to disable this fields by adding `disabled` attribute. Then add css rules to the `.disabled` class to make it like plain text (remove paddings, margins, borders etc.). Then on `dblClick` event just remove class and attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create another view for edit? since you're going to need different events separate inside of the edit view. Here is something I put together in jsfiddle

You can essentially create a new view passing the model that gets updated to the new view and show it in a region

```
newValue = ev.target.value;
this.model.set('contentPlacement', newValue)

mainView = new MainView({ model: this.model });
App.mainRegion.show(mainView)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cLPfw/